Surreal numbers by Knuth, the "bad numbers" proof.
This question is about the "Bad numbers" proof (Chapter 4, pages 24-25).
This is a proof by contradiction for sets of three numbers, so that:
$x \leq y,\ and\  y \leq z,\ then\ x \leq z$
Now, Knuth instead proves this by contradiction, namely by contradicting the following:
$x \leq y,\ and\  y \leq z,\ then\ x \nleq z$
The proof states that the latter statement will give rise to two triplets of more such bad numbers:
$(y, z, x_L)$ and $(z_R, x, y)$
Now, these triplets will still have $x_L \geq z$ and $x \geq z_R)$, respectively. And the proof is that since this can be repeated infinitely many times, and since at every pair of triplets, we're getting older and older numbers (simpler and simpler), it must be false.
What I'm having trouble wrapping my head around is that even for the non contradictory case, we can do the same thing:

$x \leq y,\ and\  y \leq z,\ then\ x \leq z$
$x \leq y,\ and\  y \leq z,\ then\ x \leq z_R$ (also implies $Z_R \neq \phi$, which may mean $x\ \ngeq Z_R$ is not the same as $\exists z_R \in Z_R \ so\ that\  x \leq z_R$)
...

And so forth.
So are both of these false?
What am I missing?
Is it that since $x \nleq z$, one or more of the conditions for $x \leq z$ fails, requiring that $X_L$ and $Z_R$ be non-empty?
There may be a subtle difference between $\nleq$ and $\leq$ when employed over sets: the latter implying the set $\neq \phi$.
(I have a feeling it has to do with empty sets vs. the use of non empty sets, but I'm not sure at this stage).

Dredging from deep memory.  The idea here was to replace $x$, $y$, and $z$ as $$x_R \leq y_L \text{ and } y_R \leq z_L \implies x_R \leq z_L  \text{.}  $$  But also, you can restrict $x$, $y$, and $z$ to their subsets that exist on day $n$ and the inequalities above have to hold for every choice of $n$.  But on a given $n$, there are only finitely many elements to choose from so there can't be infinitely long chains of distinct numbers...

I'm not very sure I understand your statement, it seems to not be the contradiction but what we're trying to prove.

The key here is that $x\leq z$ means, by definition, that there does not exist $z_R$ or $x_L$ with certain properties. So if you have a statement like "$x\le y$ and $y\le z$ and $x\le z$", then you have a lot of things that you know don't exist, but don't know that anything in particular exists, so can't make a chain of things that exist, etc.
For a very different example of the same sort of idea: let's say that a positive integer $n$ is "badly composite" if it can be written as a product $ab$ of integers $a,b>1$, where at least one of $a$ or $b$ is also badly composite. A badly composite integer can't exist since the $a,b>1$ condition would lead to a chain (an infinite sequence) of smaller and smaller badly composite positive integers (at most half the size each time).
In contrast, an integer that's not badly composite can't be written as such a product, so without some other fact about what products it might be written as, you can't make a smaller "not badly composite" number out of it. All you know is there's not a pair of factors $a,b$ with a certain property.
